# Android app Image tagging

Tags: android, image, tagging

I am working on an android application where user can upload pictures to a stream. The user can also tag the pictures with some labels. The problem is how can I detect the "same" point on an image on multiple screens? what are the possible ways of doing the same ?

Thanks.

Comment: by same point do you mean the same x,y co-ordinate, or do u mean the same offset or do u mean the same location relative to the picture boundaries?

Comment: same location on image..

Comment: @user1504005 How did you build the base tagging functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this by cropping the image in a predefined fixed aspect ratio and map x,y as per current view dimensions.